# Access previous values of a class attribute

Tags: python

```
from collections import defaultdict


class History:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__ = defaultdict()

    def __getattr__(self,name):
        if name[0] not in self.__dict__:
            raise NameError 
        return self.__dict__[name]

    def __getitem__(self,index):
        pass

    def __setattr__(self,name,value):
        if name[0] in self.__dict__:
            self.__dict__[name]= value 
        elif name[0] not in self.__dict__:
            if '_prev' in name:
                raise NameError
            else:
                self.__dict__[name]= value


if __name__ == '__main__':
# Put in simple tests for History before allowing driver to run

print()
import driver

driver.default_file_name = 'bsc2.txt'
#     driver.default_show_traceback = True
#     driver.default_show_exception = True
#     driver.default_show_exception_message = True
driver.driver()
```

#### Instruction

Write the `__getattr__` method to allow the names of attributes with any number (one or more) of `_prev` suffixes to return the correct (previous, previous to previous, etc. hint: `str.count` method) value. If some number (one or more) of `_prev` does not appear as part of the suffix, or the name before the first `_prev` suffix is not an attribute of the class, raise a `NameError` exception with an appropriate string describing the problem/values. If the number of _prev suffixes is too large (there aren't that many previous values), this method should return the value `None`.

#### My question

I am working on the `__getattr__(self,name)` method. The correct results are listed followed:

```
  e-->x.a-->3
  ^-->x.q__prev-->NameError # a new test
  e-->x.a_prev-->2
  e-->x.a_prev_prev-->1
  e-->x.a_prev_prev_prev-->None
  ^-->x.c_prev_prev-->NameError
```

but I failed to return the value which has '_prev' in the end which got the following Error:

```
 17 *Error: x.a_prev raised exception KeyError: 'a_prev'
 18 *Error: x.a_prev_prev raised exception KeyError: 'a_prev_prev'
 19 *Error: x.a_prev_prev_prev raised exception KeyError: 'a_prev_prev_prev'
```

Can someone tell me how to fix it? (function `__getattr__`)

Comment: Why would you do `if name[0] not in self.__dict__` instead of `if name not in self.__dict__`? Why would you check either of them to raise an exception? It would be raised anyway. Why would you have your own `__getattr__` which reads from `__dict__`? That also happens anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, you want to (have to?) write a class that offers a history for all of its attributes.

To achieve this you need to keep a backup of all previous values. You can do this by using a second dictionary (I called mine `history`) and move the old values there before you overwrite them. If you want to access the history, count how many `"_prev"` suffixes you find and index the history list for the attribute.

```
class History:
    def __init__(self):
        self.history = dict()

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        # how many steps to go back
        offset = name.count("_prev")
        # keep only the attribute name. There most certainly is a better way to do this.
        attr_name = name.split("_prev")[0]

        if attr_name not in self.__dict__:
            raise NameError
        elif (attr_name not in self.history) and (offset > 0):
            # return None for values that do not have a history yet
            return None
        else:
            if offset > len(self.history[attr_name]):
                # return None for all queries running out of the history
                # like a_prev_prev_prev for only two set values
                return None
            else:
                # return the 'historic' value.
                # subtract one for the active value
                return self.history[attr_name][offset-1]

    def _save_old_value(self, name):
        if name in self.history:
            # attribute is already in the history
            # prepend the activ value it to the history list
            self.history[name].insert(0, self.__dict__[name])
        else:
            # attribute is not in the history
            # create new list in the history dict
            self.history[name] = [self.__dict__[name]]

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name in self.__dict__:
            # the attribute has already been set so you need to backup the value
            self._save_old_value(name)
            self.__dict__[name] = value
        elif name not in self.__dict__:
            # the attribute is new
            if '_prev' in name:
                # prevent attribute names with _prev suffix so
                # that the user can not destroy the history
                raise NameError
            else:
                # everything is fine, add the value
                self.__dict__[name] = value
```

For me this worked out. Hopefully this covers all of the edge cases:

```
h = History()
h.a = 1
h.a = 2
h.a = 3
h.a = 4

h.b = 17

h.a
4

h.a_prev
3

h.a_prev_prev
2

h.a_prev_prev_prev
1

h.a_prev_prev_prev_prev
None

h.b
17

h.b_prev
None

h.x
NameError

h.x_prev
NameError
```

Comment: thanks, but, Is it possible to get the same result without defining a new function?